# How do I run Flash interactively in an MFC app?

Tags: apache-flex, mfc, visual-c++, air

I want to know if its possible to embed a flash movie inside an MFC app and let the user iteract with it. I know this is easily possible through embedding Flash activeX control. But I want the flash movie **to be able to receive input from the MFC app** (such as data and state update from the servers) and also should **let the MFC app know about user interactions** and other internal changes **via callbacks or in some other way**.

Is this possible through **Flex** SDK, Adobe **AIR** or such runtimes ? Pls give me some starters so that I can get up and goin with it.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I don't know c++.

You could try to embedded it as an activeX and establish communication via [ExternalInterface](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Flivedocs.adobe.com%2Fflash%2F9.0%2FActionScriptLangRefV3%2Fflash%2Fexternal%2FExternalInterface.html&ei=xGiaStP6NJPUjAfPt7WkBQ&usg=AFQjCNE-H7QxSacsRnVZoHaW_VJW2ad-8A&sig2=POaeBaTs3FxEWJJ3Sslcmg).

You can open applications with parameters e.g. photoshop.exe myFile.psd using AIR It was a bit flaky in AIR 1.0, but maybe they fixed those issues in AIR 1.5. I'm not up to date with 1.5

I would also recommend giving [mProjector](http://www.screentime.com/software/mprojector/) a try. mProjector is a projector tool, meaning it allows you to create desktop applications out of swfs. Some of the differences are: it doesn't have any dependencies( runs as a native applicaiton, deosn't require a runtime ) and it is commercial, but I think it's worth the money.

There is an [executeApplicaiton](http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/docs/AS3-mSys-executeApplicatio.htm) method that allows you to call another app with params, like air does. You have registry support and you can create [plugins](http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/plugins.html) using C++ which is what I think might get you going.

Try with ExternalInterface first though.